# How to convert numpy decimal arrays into binary arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

do you know to convert this np array into a binary one?
eg
AI=np.array([15,4,6,6])

and I want to get this:
AI=([1111, 0100, 0110, 0110])

Comment: What is the desired type for the entries for the output? Should that be an array of integers (i.e. `[1111,100,110,110]`) or an array of strings (i.e. `['1111','0100','0110','0110']`?

Comment: Also, please explain what you've tried so far

Comment: One approach (for an array of strings) is `[*map("{:04b}".format,AI)]`

Comment: I am trying to get ints for the output. Also, this is I have been trying to run x = [15,4,6,6]

# convert decimal to binary
b = [bin(i) for i in x]
print(b)

Comment: Great thanks! Please [edit] that information into the question

Comment: What is the difference in your mind between having the **integer** 0100 as the fourth element of the array and having the integer 100 as that element? How would Python distinguish between those two possibilities? Note that `0100` is not actually a valid way to write an integer in Python.

Comment: This question needs to be asked in a much clearer way. For example, what do you want to do with this result? Are you certain you want the result to be `int` type? Surely this makes no sense at all: the integer 110 is not the same as the number 6. And please format your code. Read this > https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

As you need  "*to get ints for the output*"

```
import numpy as np
AI=np.array([15,4,6,6])

out=[int(bin(i).replace("0b", "")) for i in AI]
print(out)
```

**Output:**

```
[1111, 100, 110, 110]
```